# How to interpret perf-script output

Tags: c, linux-kernel, perf

I'm trying to create a tool similar to [flamegraph](http://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html), but using a different frontend. I'm having some issues to understand the output of perf-script.

First of all, I record the `perf` data with `perf record -a -g -o /my/output/file.data`, if I understood correctly how `perf` works, this will take samples every certain time and see where the IP is at that moment.

Then I generate the perf-script output (the one I'm planning to parse) with `perf script -i /my/input/file.data --fields trace:comm,pid,tid,cpu,time,event,ip,sym,dso,trace`, and I get the following output:

```
...
swapper     0 [000] 22925.999132:      68882 cycles: 
        ffffffffa9311275 rcu_prepare_for_idle+0x5 ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffffa93131be rcu_irq_exit+0x6e ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffffa9c01d4f call_function_single_interrupt+0xf ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffffa99060d4 cpuidle_enter_state+0xc4 ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffffa99064d9 cpuidle_enter+0x29 ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffffa92c431e do_idle+0x1de ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffffa92c4559 cpu_startup_entry+0x19 ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffffaa91617b start_kernel+0x58c ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffffa92000d4 secondary_startup_64+0xa4 ([kernel.kallsyms])
...
```

I don't understand what the time (`22925.999132`) means.

I also don't understand the meaning of the cycle counter, at first I thought that it was for how long the function was executing, but if it's just sampling the IP it makes no sense to have this information.

Comment: Time is in format seconds.microseconds. Zero may be linux kernel boot time. Best documentation is the source code https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/builtin-script.c - "if (PRINT_FIELD(TIME)) {" - it even has some mode of relative time "reltime" - `OPT_BOOLEAN(0, "reltime", &reltime, "Show time stamps relative to start"),`  (`perf script --reltime`)